# following Add points to a web map tutorial part 3 leaves me with a blank page

Tags: mapbox

I was following this guide, https://docs.mapbox.com/help/tutorials/add-points-pt-3/#add-a-map-to-a-webpage and when I load my index.html in my browser it is completely white.

```
<html lang='en'>
  <head>
    <meta charset='utf-8' />
    <title>Points on a map</title>
    <meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1' />
    <script src='https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/v2.9.1/mapbox-gl.js'></script>
    <link href='https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/v2.9.1/mapbox-gl.css' rel='stylesheet' />
    <style>
      body { 
        margin: 0; 
        padding: 0; 
      }
      #map { 
        position: absolute; 
        top: 0; 
        bottom: 0; 
        width: 100%; 
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id='map'></div>
    <script>
    // The value for 'accessToken' begins with 'pk...'
    mapboxgl.accessToken = 'i put my token here'; 
    const map = new mapboxgl.Map({
      container: 'map',
      // Replace YOUR_STYLE_URL with your style URL.
      style: 'Redacted', 
      center: [Also Redacted],
      zoom: 11.79
    });

    // Code from the next step will go here.

    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you have this running somewhere? Hard to determine what the issue might be without seeing this in action